# functions result is NaN

Tags: javascript

I am really new in coding therefore I am coding currently a Taximeter. Unfortunately is the result of my code when executing NaN in the console. I tried some ways to rectify my problem but those attempts did not work. I think that some variables are not in the right scope but I do not know how to fix that.

```
function Taximeter() {
    const y = 3.9;
    const km = prompt("How far is your target");

    if (km <= 7) {
        var routePrice = 2.3;
    } else if (km > 7) {
        let routePrice = 1.65;
        var subtractedLength = (km -= 7);
        var partialExpenses = (subtractedLength *= routePrice);
        var tosevenExpenses = 7 * 2.3;
        var combinedExpenses = (tosevenExpenses += partialExpenses);
    }

    const persons = prompt("How much persons are driving with you?");
    if (persons > 8) {
        console.log("Only 8 persons can drive with you.");
    } else if (8 >= persons >= 5) {
        var personsExpenses = 5;
    } else if (0 >= persons >= 4) {
        personExpenses = 0;
    }

    if (km <= 7) {
        var wholeExpenses = y + km * routePrice + personsExpenses;
    } else {
        var wholeExpenses = combinedExpenses + y + personsExpenses;
    }
    console.log(wholeExpenses);
}
```

Comment: `8 >= persons >= 5` looks very suspicious.

Comment: Use a tool like ESLINT to help you follow best practices. You have a lot of problems with variable hoisting in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be helpful to know where exactly `NaN` is coming up and whether or not you are seeing `NaN` as the result of an `Exception` (if an error message was logged to the console) or if `NaN` is coming up as a result of your own `console.log()` statements. Part of the issue could be that the function `prompt()` returns a `String`, meaning that your variable `km` is going to be a `String` and not a `Number`. Use this line of code instead and it might fix your problem:

```
const km =  parseInt(prompt("How far is your target"));
```

###### EDIT:

In response to your comment, there are a couple other issues I see here. There is the issue with your first `if` and `else if` clauses where the indentation is a little off. This, as far as I can tell, should not actually affect your code, but it does make it harder to read. Here is how it should look:

```
if (km <= 7) {
    var routePrice = 2.3;
} else if (km > 7) {
    let routePrice = 1.65
    var subtractedLength = km -= 7;
    var partialExpenses = subtractedLength *= routePrice ;
    var tosevenExpenses = 7 *2.3;
    var combinedExpenses = tosevenExpenses += partialExpenses;
};
```

Second, in those same `if` and `else if` clauses, you use the `-=`, `*=`, and `+=` operators when they are unnecessary and may cause errors. I've never seen them used the way that you have before, so I don't know if they actually cause errors, but I would edit those clauses one more time for readability at least:

```
if (km <= 7) {
    var routePrice = 2.3;
} else if (km > 7) {
    let routePrice = 1.65
    var subtractedLength = km - 7;
    var partialExpenses = subtractedLength * routePrice ;
    var tosevenExpenses = 7 *2.3;
    var combinedExpenses = tosevenExpenses + partialExpenses;
};
```

Like with `km` I would also edit your `persons` declaration to turn that variable into a `Number` so that the logic operators that you use on it later work properly:

```
const persons = parseInt(prompt("How much persons are driving with you?"));
```

Another thing, like a commenter earlier pointed out, `8 >= persons >= 5` will not work the way you think it will - just edit those `if` and `else if` clauses like so to fix that error:

```
if (persons > 8) {
    console.log("Only 8 persons can drive with you.");
} else if(persons >= 5 && persons <= 8) {
    var personsExpenses = 5;
} else if (persons <= 4 && persons >= 0) {
    personExpenses = 0;
};
```

Finally, your variable declaration of `personsExpenses` is such that the variable will only be declared if that first `else if` clause resolves. You need `personsExpenses` to be declared no matter what, so I would declare it before and outside of any of those conditional clauses:

```
var personsExpenses
if (persons > 8) {
    console.log("Only 8 persons can drive with you.");
} else if(persons >= 5 && persons <= 8) {
     personsExpenses = 5;
} else if (persons <= 4 && persons >= 0) {
     personExpenses = 0;
};
```

That's everything that I noticed, so good luck!

Comment: There are a couple of other additional issues that I can see within the code that might cause problems later on, but I don't think that those other issues I can see are what caused the particular error you are asking about.

Comment: which issues do you else see?

Comment: The NaN result appears without an error message. The NaN is the result of console.log()

Comment: Hopefully, my edited answer provides some assistance.